# Typecasting for vector pushback operation in C++

Tags: c++, types, vector, casting, push-back

I have two vectors

```
std::vector<std::string> outputStack, operatorStack;
```

At some point, I need to pop some elements out of one stack and push it into another stack.

```
while(operatorStack.back().compare(L_BRACKET)) {
    outputStack.push_back(operatorStack.pop_back());
}
```

However, eclipse throws an error, invalid arguments. But works fine when I type cast the input.

```
outputStack.push_back((std::string)operatorStack.pop_back());
```

Now, why is this typecasting needed? I was reading (mostly in C++ Primer) that typecasting needs to be avoided according to C++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::vector::pop_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) returns `void`. You need to get the [`back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) first, *then* pop it.

```
outputStack.push_back(operatorStack.back());
operatorStack.pop_back();
```

This is quite common in standard library container `pop` functions, for exception safety reasons. A value_type returning pop would generally imply a copy construction, which could throw, meaning the container will lose an element that isn't copied succesfully by the caller. So `pop()` and `back()` or `front()` operations are separated.

Answer (score 4):

[`pop_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) doesn't return an element. It has a void return. Even though Eclipse isn't complaining, I would be shocked if that cast will compile (it most certainly shouldn't).

Since `pop_back` in C++ does not actually return the popped element, you need to grab it with [`back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `std::vector::back()` to get the value of last element instead of [std::vector::pop_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) as pop_back simply removes element from back and return void.

Also  need to compare `std::string::compare` with `std::string::npos`

```
while(operatorStack.back().compare(L_BRACKET) == 0) {
    outputStack.push_back(operatorStack.back());
    operatorStack.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that string::compare does not return bool.

Comment: It's true that `std::string::compare` does not return `bool`; however, comparing to `npos` is **not** the right answer. Compare to `0` to see if the two strings are equal. Beyond that, read the documentation.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for pointing it out, I mixed it with std::string::find